# NHibernate - Mapping a collection of components?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have the following DB Table

```
CREATE TABLE ProductPrice
  ProductID
  Qty1
  Price1
  Qty2
  Price2
  Qty3
  Price3
```

My domain classes look like this

```
Class ProductPrice
  ProductID As Integer
  PriceBands As IList(of PriceBand)
End Class

Class PriceBand
  Qty As Integer
  Price As Decimal
End Class
```

I know we can use the "component" mapping to map a single row into different objects but is it possible to map a collection of objects as described above?

Many Thanks

James

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't wish to use a real collection mapped to a proper table? That would be the recommended solution.

Comment: It's a legacy table I'm afraid so I'm stuck with it. I obviously wouldn't have designed it this way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you can, normalize your database into two tables - products and product prices (each row containing product ID, quantity and price band for that quantity, insead having them like 3 pairs of columns). then you will easily map them as collections (bags) in NHibernate to match your application model classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think seeing 1,2,3 at the end of field names is usually a sign of bad database design so I'd be kind of surprised if NH supported this.

Comment: As I said above I can't change the table design. Is there a way to do a manual mapping at all?